# For loop just returns last string in array

Tags: java, bukkit

This code should rename each item in `Kits` that you configure in the *config.yml*.
However, iterating through the array that holds all the names, just renames all the items to the last string in the array.

```
try {

    String getKits = getConfig().getString("Kits." + args[0] + ".Items");

    String[] kits = getKits.split(",");

    for (String s1 : kits) {

        String[] singleKits = s1.split("-");

        ItemStack kit = new ItemStack(Integer.valueOf(singleKits[0]), Integer.valueOf(singleKits[1]));
        ItemMeta kitDisplayName = kit.getItemMeta();

        String[] itemNames = getConfig().getString("Kits." + args[0] + ".names").split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
            kitDisplayName.setDisplayName(itemNames[i]);
            kit.setItemMeta(kitDisplayName);
        }

        pInv.addItem(kit);

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the array `args`?

Comment: Why is an array if it's just a kit name?

Comment: What do you expect from this code? `for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
            kitDisplayName.setDisplayName(itemNames[i]);
            kit.setItemMeta(kitDisplayName); }`. This is going to reset the name every time until the last `i` which is what you're seeing unless `setDisplayName` and `setItemMeta` add stuff to an array (which i highly doubt but can't say for sure since you haven't added the entire code).

Comment: @Okx Sorry, I should have said that it _contains_ the kit name. The whole code is a command executor, and a command may have several arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner for-loop will iterate through all names and always end at the last one.
Because of that this block of code will set the displayname to the same value for each (outer) loop.

```
String[] itemNames = getConfig().getString("Kits." + args[0] + ".names").split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
            kitDisplayName.setDisplayName(itemNames[i]);
            kit.setItemMeta(kitDisplayName);
        }
```

If your items and names are in the same order you should use the number from the outer for-loop to fetch the correct name:

```
String[] kits = getConfig().getString("Kits." + args[0] + ".Items").split(",");
String[] itemNames = getConfig().getString("Kits." + args[0] + ".names").split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < kits.length; i++) {

    String[] singleKits = kits[i].split("-");

    ItemStack kit = new ItemStack(Integer.valueOf(singleKits[0]), Integer.valueOf(singleKits[1]));
    ItemMeta kitDisplayName = kit.getItemMeta();

    kitDisplayName.setDisplayName(itemNames[i]);
    kit.setItemMeta(kitDisplayName);
}
```